# How to pass environment array configuration properties with docker-compose dynamically?

Tags: asp.net-core, docker-compose, .net-core-3.1

I have an `ASP .NET Core Web API` app that is deployed on a docker linux container.

Now I need to upgrade my app configuration including an emails array, it is not a problem until I need to pass this array using `docker-compose.yml`.

This is the C# code I use to retrieve the configuration:

```cs
List<string> emails = _config.GetSection("Checker:EMails").Get<List<string>>();
```

These are my linux environments variables as explained by [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#json-configuration-provider):

```sh
export Checker__RefreshTime="86400000"
export Checker__DaysToCheck="15"

#emails array
export Checker__EMails__0="my_email1@my.com"
export Checker__EMails__1="my_email2p@my.com"
```

`docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
environment:
            # the following line passes the host environment var to the container created from the image
            
            # Checker configuration
            - Checker__RefreshTime=${Checker__RefreshTime}
            - Checker__DaysToCheck=${Checker__DaysToCheck}
```

How can I include the emails array dynamically without the necessity to change `docker-compose.yml` file every time? Because now I need to do something like:

```yaml
environment:
            # the following line passes the host environment var to the container created from the image
            
            # Checker configuration
            - Checker__RefreshTime=${Checker__RefreshTime}
            - Checker__DaysToCheck=${Checker__DaysToCheck}
            - Checker__EMails__0=${Checker__EMails__0}
            - Checker__EMails__1=${Checker__EMails__1}
            # etc..
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an file to store the environment variables and call the file from your docker-compose file.
Instead of:

```
environment:
            - Checker__RefreshTime=${Checker__RefreshTime}
            - Checker__DaysToCheck=${Checker__DaysToCheck}
            - Checker__EMails__0=${Checker__EMails__0}
            - Checker__EMails__1=${Checker__EMails__1}
```

use:

```
env_file: filename.env
```

Comment: This can be a partial solution, what I'm looking for is a way to use the Net Core configuration out of the box array vars management.